# Creating a form for registrating three users in JavaFX

Tags: user-interface, javafx

Context

1. Developing a Login/Registration page
2. Security is very important
3. To reduce code complexity, I want to use just one controller and FXML page.

I want to create a form to register three users at once. Below you see an example to get a better picture what I am looking for.

Each user need to enter their credentials that are getting saved via smartcard. This would mean that one user after the other would need to enter their credentials and each user has its own smartcard.

What would be the most elegant way to solve this from technical and additonally user point of view.

Please no comments about layout, this is still in progress.

[image]

Comment: I would setup the UI to only register a single user. If you want a flow where users are registered one after the other, you can set up a "wizard" like component. When one user registers, update the UI to begin registering the next user. You could even have it so that all users are only _truly_ registered (i.e., entered into the database/whatever) once every user has entered their passwords. Note this does not require having multiple FXML files or controllers, though it will probably require having multiple _instances_ of the single FXML/controller.

Comment: Considering multiple people are signing up. I would generate temp passwords that the users can change later after they have successfully signed into the app.

Comment: It says the credentials are saved to a smart card.  There may be no app, it could be a one-off initialization of a smart card (or set of cards).   I don't know that these kinds of fairly open-ended UI and app design questions are a good fit for StackOverflow (I don't know of an alternative forum for such questions).

Comment: Yeah, it is important to consider that during the registration process each user needs to insert their own smartcard. The application needs to check for each user if a new smartcard has been inserted. @Slaw has a good idea to reload the dialogue for each user if the previous user has been successfully registered. This would help to reduce code complexity, one controller and one fxml.

Comment: This is inherently a bit complex.  I wouldn't put overarching emphasis on reducing code complexity, but instead on designing the best user experience, and then designing the data models and code required to support that experience.